# Cocos2d - lunar eclipse effect on iPhone

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, cocos2d-iphone, glsl

i have a question about achieving an effect like on a lunar eclipse. The effect should look like in the first seconds of this gif. So just like a black shadow which goes over the circle. The ideal situation would be a function where i can passed a parameter in percentage to get this amount as a shadow on the circle:

[image: lunar eclipse]

The problem which i am facing is that my background is an gradient. So it's not possible to have a black circle which moves over the moon to get the effect.

[image: situation]

I tried something with `CCClippingNode` but it looks not nice. Furthermore the clip on the edges was always a bit pixelated.

I thought about using something like a GLSL Shader to achieve the effect but i am not so familiar with GLSL and i can't find an example.

The effect is for an app game developed for an iphone. I use the cocos2d framework in version 3 (the current one).

Has somebody an idea how to get this effect? An idea where i can start to search?

Thank you in advance

Comment: You can get lost with implementing shaders ... I found the learning curve quite stiff ... but they can give spectacular effects. Look [here](https://www.shadertoy.com/view/lslXDr) for an example that comes close. Browse that site, lots of examples and sample code.

Comment: @YvesLeBorg Thanks for the nice site. I will check some of those shaders. But it looks a bit to heavy for the performance. But i will try. But in general do you know any other solution to get the effect with cocos2d help? CCRenderTexture maybe?

Comment: unfortunately not,  now that i did the learning, shaders are my 'goto' solution for tricky graphics. btw, i get very respectable perf with shaders even on lowly antique devices. Shaders are very efficient, you just have to know and understand the automatic draw-call batching in v3.x.

Comment: Is there also an automatic draw-call batching with shaders in cocos2d (only know for sprites right now)? Ok so your suggestion is to use shaders?

Comment: A shader is applied to a sprite, changing the rendering. A few things interrupt the auto-batching of sprites, shader is one : read [this](https://github.com/cocos2d/cocos2d-objc/wiki/Cocos2D-Render-Order-and-Batching) to get the complete story. When you plan to use shaders, you have to make certain you add your 'shaded' sprites at the end of a long stream of sprites that come from a single texture. Finally, I am saying i would go that route. The answer below is clever (1D texture, less math), and let the shader do the pixel manipulations (very fast).

Answer (score 3):

The [physics behind](http://www.skyandtelescope.com/press-releases/get-ready-for-sunday-nights-total-eclipse-of-the-moon/) is simple you change the light shining on the moon. So

1. **I would create a 1D gradient texture representing the lighting conditions**

   [image]
   [image]
2. **compute each rendered pixel of moon**

   you obviously have the 2D texture of moon. So you now need to obtain the position of each pixel inside the 1D lighting texture. So if moon is fully visible you are in sunlight. When partially eclipsed then you are in the umbra region. And finaly while total eclipse you are in penumbra region. so just compute the middle point's of the moon position. And for the rest use relative position in the moons motion direction.

   [image: texture coord]

   So now just multiply the Moon surface with the lighting texture and render the output.
3. **when working you can add the curvature correction**

   Now you got linerly cutted Moon phases but the real phases are curved as the lighting conditions differs also with radial distance from motion direction and moons center. To fix this you can do

   - convert the lighting to 2D texture
   - or shift the texture coordinate by some curvature dependent on the radial distance

Comment: clever , clever@2x for the minimum character count on a comment!

Comment: if i just write `clever` in a comment, SO complains (too short), so I have to write a lengthy sentence to compliment you. which i did. sorry for the confusion.