# How to programmatically generate pictures of moon phases?

Tags: image-processing, graphics, gimp

How do I generate images of the different moon phases?

i.e., I want something like this:

[image: waxing gibbous]

and I'm thinking about overlapping two images to get that kind of result, for example

[image: new moon] & [image: full moon]

based on U.S. Navy moon illumination data (any alternatives?)

> Moon calendar for 2016: 
>   http://aa.usno.navy.mil/cgi-bin/aa_moonill2.pl?form=2&year=2016&task=00&tz=6&tz_sign=-1

I made the first image with GIMP, so I'm thinking about automating that process with a GIMP script fed with the parsed moon data (illuminated fraction, at first).

I'm looking for a non-gimp dependent alternative.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/q/33258872/2521214 for some additional ideas

Comment: @paranoidhominid Could u plz tell me the status of the moon from the particular day..I am also woking on it..Plz help me ..Thanks

Comment: @RavindraKushwaha I found this API for moon phase data I hope it is useful to you https://www.aerisweather.com/develop/

Comment: Thanks for ur input :) ...I have managed through my code :P..Again thanks

Answer (score 1):

- Get a selection on the moon (likely, Alpha-to-selection)
- Save to channel
- Remove the selection
- Scale the saved channel horizontally (vertically centered)
- Recreate the original selection
- Subtract the scaled channel
- Subtract on the halves of the image
- Bucket-fill the remaining selection

The horizontal scaling factor is likely to be a cosine of the POM day.

[image: POM]

Answer (score 0):

A completely different, and non-Gimp-dependent alternative: generate a SVG file directly. In practice you would have a base image on which you would overlay a crescent (which is, like in my other answer, a half circle on one side and a half-ellipse on the other. Creating a Bezier spline that very closely approximates a circle arc or an ellipse arc is very easy.